# Why don't GPU fans have a housing unlike the other fans?

Tags: gpu, fan

Why don't GPU fans have a housing on the fans themselves unlike case, CPU, chipset, and PSU fans?

Comment: Housings exist to focus air flow given the constraints of the case or device being cooled and the preferences of the fan designer and purchaser.  For instance, my GPU fan does have a housing and my CPU fan doesn't, and they both work decently well at their intended function.

Answer (score 1):

It is a function of how design engineers design the fan. If they do not see any undue exposure, they can save money by not providing a space for a housing. The supports they provide for the fan does the job.

Case and CPU fans are more exposed (in the machines I see) so warrant a housing.

Here is an arbitrary photo which shows that a GPU fan may or may not have additional support and that would depend on the engineering design.

[image: Fan support photos]